# Xfwm4 crashes with falling horizontal distorted bars after resuming a suspend/sleep

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, xfce, monitor, xfwm4

This issue happens infrequently, maybe weeks, months in between. I am using nvidia proprietary drivers and a 3070 card. This was also not happening prior to Ubuntu 20.04.

The issue is both monitors see black horizontal bars start filling in and falling from the top to the bottom covering the screen after resuming from a suspend/sleep state (computer was running over night).

Mouse still moves, and I am able to get to the virtual terminal to run `killall xfwm4` with fixes the issue.

Syslog doesn't really show any specific errors around this that I can see.

[image: Picture of falling display bars final form]

Note: The only apps I had open were Firefox and mousepad. No obvious logs in xsession or syslogs.

Seems like a similar bug was reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-xenial/+bug/1643843

Comment: Could it be possible the video card or chips are going bad?

Comment: I've checked temperatures and they're normal. The cpu and gpu are both new (within 1 year), and on the more upper end of cards / chips. I don't see anything that suggest that unfortunately.

Comment: The bars and other issues with the monitor say it can be the card. Something the day you buy it can be bad or go bad at any time.

Comment: Do you know of any method to test the health of the card? Just through bios tests? Or another method

Comment: Try a manjaro xfce live image. (That ensures you're not in the "debian" realms). Suspend/resume the live image. Alternatively blacklist nvidia and try the nouveau drivers -to ensure that your card is not the culprit. Last not least: are you using XServer or wayland session??

Comment: I'll try those things out. The bounty is leaving before I can test, but I'll make sure to include another one if this turns out to be true for you to claim. I'm using classic Xubuntu, and $XDG_SESSION_TYPE shows X11. So one thing of note is I've updated my nvidia driver to latest mainline, and also I've changed sleep mode to just "Blank", and the issue hasn't come up recently. Will update later if that changes.

Comment: Note: I updated nvidia driver, and changed battery management display to "Blank" instead of turn off or sleep. After about a week the issue arose again. Logs show snap->cups errors, so I've removed. Will update if any change.

Comment: Also I had 0 disk space this morning, so I've cleared up 200GB, and will see if that has affected anything long term.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this issue occur again in 3 months after setting the power manager to only blank at 45minutes rather than sleep or switch off.

Seems like the issue was it going to sleep and resuming crashing the desktop manager / display.